Are there canonical definitions for the maps symbols used in "The Adjustment Bureau"?
In the movie "The Adjustment Bureau" we see the adjusters watching the progress of "The Plan" in notebooks with dynamic maps.

Like any well-done movie prop or concept, the imagination behind those maps is fascinating! I know that it's altogether possible that the design of the dynamic maps is purely artistic and reflect nothing more than the emotion behind the circumstances of a particular scene, but I'm wondering if the symbols in the map design have either a canonical or conceptual meaning beyond looking pretty?

Question: Has the director or artistic teams involved with The Adjustment Bureau ever explained the meaning behind the dynamic map symbols?

Not specifically what you're after but they briefly talk over the initial origin concepts - which seem to be quite vague at first and could have come from anywhere initially:


What Brainstorm Digital has done on this project?
Brainstorm Digital did a lot of invisible effects such as greenscreen comps, shot fixes and enhancements. ... Our main focus however was the design, animation and integration of the planbooks to work within the story as part mystery and part plot illustration.


What references have you received for the book’s content?
None. We read the script, listened closely to George and gave revision after revision until it honed in on what he wanted.  The first pitches were a really wide net referencing circular astronomical and nautical designs to circuit boards and Kindles versus books. We were steered to a circuit board diagram in an old ledger book feel immediately and from there the design changes really had to do with the animation and the way the main character’s icons felt.

https://www.artofvfx.com/the-adjustment-bureau-mark-russell-superviseur-vfx-de-la-production-2/
Also look at the movie prop close ups:

https://www.ross-macdonald.com/movie-props#/the-adjustment-bureau/
As for the other symbols and markers used in the planbooks I haven't seen anything yet.
There was a website that had the inspirations listed (one was the moleskin look, from Modern Timber Engineering by Walter Scofield, see below) but the site is dead, so that info is gone unless re-posted elsewhere since.
https://www.yourprops.com/Hero-Map-Book-original-movie-prop-The-Adjustment-Bureau-2011-YP53203.html
https://propstoreauction.com/lot-details/index/catalog/318/lot/95489
https://sheldongalleries.co.uk/product/the-adjustment-bureau-by-christian-petersen/
https://propstore.com/product/adjustment-bureau-the-2011/reference-map-book/

This brown leather-effect bounded book entitled ‘Modern Timber Engineering’ by W. Fleming Scofield and W. H. O’Brien was the main inspiration of the Adjuster’s ledgers in the film. These ledgers are used by the Adjusters to track time and movement. When the books are opened, they feature a moving map of the people and scenarios that the Adjusters are monitoring. Through these maps, they can alter fate and outcomes. The illustrations inside the book are reminiscent of what is seen on screen, and were the main inspiration to the maps in the ledgers.


Consisting of an actual published 6 x 9 in. hardbound book, Modern Timber Engineering by Scofield O'Brien (1942), repurposed with a studio-printed diagram pasted as a spread over pages 106 and 107. Engineered for easy opening to the necessary pages by Matt Damon

https://entertainment.ha.com/itm/movie-tv-memorabilia/prop-book-from-the-adjustment-bureau/a/997018-2646.s

The “Plan Book” graphics, which were represented in an Art Deco style, were highlighted by animated rays of sunlight breaking through cracks in overhead clouds.

https://www.shootonline.com/spw/gravity-creates-dramatic-and-unique-visual-effects-universal-pictures-adjustment-bureau/
